# React on OSX how to set location

Tags: macos, reactjs

I'm very new in React. I would like to create a new project, based on [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html) I should use comand:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app

cd my-app
npm start
```

But how to set location of this my-app project in my computer? I would like to set it into the folder "Webs" at my iCloud Drive.

Comment: You simply go to the target directory in Terminal and enter those commands.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the directory `create-react-app` created.

`mv my-app ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Webs`

Comment: Thank you. But what if my-app is not yet created? How to set the location at the begining?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the location in the beginning, you can just navigate to your directory with

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Webs
```

and then use create-react-app from there

```
create-react-app my-app
```